# Top K Frequent Elements - time complexity: Bucket Sort vs Heap

Tags: python, time-complexity, heap, bucket-sort

I was working on a leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/) which is:

> Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.

I solved this using `min-heap` (My time complexity calculations are in comment - do correct me if I did a mistake):

```
        from collections import Counter
        
        if k == len(nums):
            return nums
        
        # O(N)
        c = Counter(nums)
        
        it = iter([(x[1], x[0]) for x in c.items()])
        
        # O(K)
        result = list(islice(it, k))
        heapify(result)
        
        # O(N-K)
        for elem in it:
            # O(log K)
            heappushpop(result, elem)
            
        # O(K)
        return [pair[1] for pair in result]
    
    # O(K) + O(N) + O((N - K) log K) + O(K log K)
    # if k < N :
    #   O(N log K)
```

Then I saw a solution using `Bucket Sort` that suppose to beat the heap solution with `O(N)`:

```
        bucket = [[] for _ in nums]

        # O(N)
        c = collections.Counter(nums)

        # O(d) where d is the number of distinct numbers. d <= N
        for num, freq in c.items():
            bucket[-freq].append(num)
            
        # O(?)
        return list(itertools.chain(*bucket))[:k]
```

How do we compute the time complexity of the `itertools.chain` call here?
Is it come from the fact that at most we will chain `N` elements? Is that enough to deduce it is O(N)?

In any case, at least on leetcode test cases the first one has better performance - what can be the reason for that?

Comment: Solution with heap should be: `c = Counter(nums): return [pair[1] for pair in nlargest(k, [(x[1], x[0]) for x in c.items()])]`. The number of comparison for `nlargest(k, n)` is **k * (1 + log(k, 2)) * (log(n/k, e) + (1/n - 1/k) / 2)** according to the source for `heapq.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of `list(itertools.chain(*bucket))` is O(N) where N is the total number of elements in the nested list `bucket`. The `chain` function is roughly equivalent to this:

```py
def chain(*iterables):
    for iterable in iterables:
        for item in iterable:
            yield item
```

The `yield` statement dominates the running time, is O(1), and executes N times, hence the result.

---

The reason your O(N log k) algorithm might end up being faster in practice is because log k is probably not very large; LeetCode says k is at most the number of distinct elements in the array, but I suspect for most of the test cases k is much smaller, and of course log k is smaller than that.

The O(N) algorithm probably has a relatively high constant factor because it allocates N lists and then randomly accesses them by index, resulting in a lot of cache misses; the `append` operations may also cause a lot of those lists to be reallocated as they become larger.

Comment: Thanks kaya. Would you recommend to use the heap over the buckets in an interview because of that constant?

Comment: The best thing to do in a real situation would be to benchmark the two solutions on realistic data, and decide between them that way. In an interview, you could suggest both solutions, discuss how you would decide between them, and implement one or the other unless there is time to implement both and the interviewers want you to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding my comment using `nlargest` seems to run more slowly than using `heapify`, etc. (see below). But the Bucket Sort, at least for this input, definitely is more performant. It would also seem that with the Bucket Sort that creating the full list of `num` elements to take the first `k` elements does not cause too much of a penalty.

```py
from collections import Counter
from heapq import nlargest
from itertools import chain

def most_frequent_1a(nums, k):
    if k == len(nums):
        return nums

    # O(N)
    c = Counter(nums)

    it = iter([(x[1], x[0]) for x in c.items()])

    # O(K)
    result = list(islice(it, k))
    heapify(result)

    # O(N-K)
    for elem in it:
        # O(log K)
        heappushpop(result, elem)

    # O(K)
    return [pair[1] for pair in result]

def most_frequent_1b(nums, k):        
    if k == len(nums):
        return nums

    c = Counter(nums)        
    return [pair[1] for pair in nlargest(k, [(x[1], x[0]) for x in c.items()])]


def most_frequent_2a(nums, k):
    bucket = [[] for _ in nums]

    # O(N)
    c = Counter(nums)

    # O(d) where d is the number of distinct numbers. d <= N
    for num, freq in c.items():
        bucket[-freq].append(num)

    # O(?)
    return list(chain(*bucket))[:k]


def most_frequent_2b(nums, k):
    bucket = [[] for _ in nums]

    # O(N)
    c = Counter(nums)

    # O(d) where d is the number of distinct numbers. d <= N
    for num, freq in c.items():
        bucket[-freq].append(num)

    # O(?)
    # don't create full list:
    i = 0
    for elem in chain(*bucket):
        yield elem
        i += 1
        if i == k:
            break

import timeit
nums = [i for i in range(1000)]
nums.append(7)
nums.append(88)
nums.append(723)
print(most_frequent_1a(nums, 3))
print(most_frequent_1b(nums, 3))
print(most_frequent_2a(nums, 3))
print(list(most_frequent_2b(nums, 3)))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='most_frequent_1a(nums, 3)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='most_frequent_1b(nums, 3)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='most_frequent_2a(nums, 3)', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='list(most_frequent_2b(nums, 3))', number=10000, globals=globals()))
```

Prints:

```
[7, 723, 88]
[723, 88, 7]
[7, 88, 723]
[7, 88, 723]
3.180169899998873
4.487235299999156
2.710413699998753
2.62860400000136
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmark - as @kaya said the nature of the input is the key here. As a side note - my implementation is almost identical to `nlargest` method. I removed a check or two and mine also skip the sorting (because not needed by the question) - maybe the gap is right there.

Comment: My last coding example, where I don't create the full list from the `chain` operation, had just about the worst possible input to demonstrate any potential savings because of the 1000 buckets the first 998 will be empty and only the last two representing counts of 2 (with 3 items) and 1 (with 997 items) occupied. So the code does avoid creating a list but `chain` will almost always have to iterate through most of the buckets anyway. This was just about a worst-case scenario.

Comment: By the way, the old card sorters in data centers used for sorting punched cards (i.e. numbers punched in certain columns) was based on the Distribution Sort (aka Bucket Sort) where you sort the cards into pockets one column at a time (least significant digit to most significant digit). So if the number occupied 6 columns, you had to make 6 passes. The "running time" was still proportional to the number of cards you had to sort (more or less).

Comment: Very interesting piece of history :) Thanks.