# Time complexity of Top K Frequent Elements in Python (Leetcode)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to understand a more efficient solution to Problem 347 on Leetcode. My solution was not as efficient. I do not understand why this solution runs in `O(n)` time.

```py
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        # count up the frequencies of each number: # O(n)
        counts = {}
        for n in nums:
            counts[n] = 1 + counts.get(n, 0) # add one to the count, default if not found is 0

        
        # create our buckets: O(n)
        freq_buckets = for [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]

        # add the counts to each of the buckets
        for num, count in counts.items():
            # for that specific frequency, add this num to the list of 
            # numbers occurring at that frequency
            freq_buckets[count].append(num)

        # hold our k most frequent
        most_frequent = []
        # iterate from most frequent to least frequent
        for i in range(len(freq_buckets) - 1, 0, -1): # O(n): loop 3
            for num in freq_buckets[i]: # O(n): loop 4
                most_frequent.append(num)

                # break when we have k most frequent
                if len(most_frequent) == k:
                    return most_frequent
```

I believed it ran in `O(kn)` time for a moment because **loop 3** would only run until **k**. However, on further inspection, I can see there is a balance between **loop 3** and **loop 4** because if the outer loop runs for `n` iterations then the inner loop could run between `0` and `n + 1` times. This leads me to believe that if the inner loop runs `n` times then we must be at the bucket of `1` which means we've iterated over the outer loop almost `n` times and then iterate over the inner loop `k` times (which could be equal to `n` if `n = k`).

There are cases that I'm struggling to reason through.
Am I correct in thinking that this algorithm does not run in `O(n)` time? If not, please explain why.

I have tried analysing the time complexities of each line and expected to find `O(n)`.

I have also read another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073941/top-k-frequent-elements-time-complexity-bucket-sort-vs-heap) but do not understand how they come to their conclusion.

Comment: loop 3 and 4 together go through exactly k steps before hitting return. And given k <= n and the rest of the function is O(n), you still get O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration of the inner loop will append one element to `most_frequent`. Once the list `most_frequent` reaches size `k`, the function will terminate. In addition, `most_frequent` does not reset every time the outer loop increments by 1. Thus, the inner loop will run at most `k` times, total, regardless of how many times the outer loop is running.

A complexity analysis on this gives O(N+K) -- N for the outer loop, and K for the inner loop. Since K <= N, this is equivalent to O(2N) ~ O(N).

The key idea here is that the inner loop is not running `k` times *for every one of the outer loop's iterations*. The number of iterations of the inner loop across all iterations of the outer loop is bounded by a constant `k`.

Comment: While I don't completely understand the logic, I appreciate your response.

Comment: Which part do you not fully understand?

Comment: Explain how you come to `O(n+k)`. I see how it is less than or equal to `n` but are you saying that because... oh. So there is a maximum running time on the inner loop of O(k)? 
And so, this leads the algorithm to never actually run `k` times for each `n`?

Comment: Exactly. Normally calculating the complexity is the outer loop times the inner loop. But this time the inner loop has a bound of `k` iterations that is not dependent on the outer loop, so it is O(N+K) instead of O(N * K).